# The requested module '/CustomCkeditor5/build/ckeditor.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ckeditor5

i have a problem when i want to user the custom configured ckeditor that i make from the online builder that said :
The requested module '/CustomCkeditor5/build/ckeditor.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

here are the code i used on my component :

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="editorData" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
    </div>
</template>
  
<script lang="ts">
import Editor from '../../../../CustomCkeditor5/build/ckeditor';

export default {
    name: 'EditorOne',
    props: ['Value'],
    data() {
        return {
            editor: Editor,
            editorData: this.Value.content,
            editorConfig: {

            }
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

i have tried adding the ckeditor5 to the vite config like this :
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

```
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
    port: 42069,
    host: true
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['CustomCkeditor5']
  },
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: {
      include: ['CustomCkeditor5']
    }
  }
})
```

i tried importing the component like this :

```
import '../../../../CustomCkeditor5/build/ckeditor';
```

but nothing seems to work